# why can't components in vue 3 be used multiple times in one component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

[image: screenshot of UI]

why can't components in vue 3 be used multiple times in one component?
like a picture above, my component cant render multiple times

```html
<div class="mb-3 row" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{ item.label }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select-two :url="item.url" @change="change($event, item.event)"></select-two>
  </div>
</div>
```

thats my looping component

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the `<select-two>` component, looks like it's rendering fine. What should it be doing? What does its code look like?

Comment: I want the select-two component to render 3 times, but as shown in the image I've pasted, it only renders once.

Comment: I cannot [reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-brahmagupta-1gjdgi?file=/src/App.vue) this. Without more information and actual code, this is not answerable

Comment: If SELECT has no OPTIONs - then it will look as on your picture.

Comment: You're looping over `items` but haven't shown where items is defined, making it impossible to answer.